# Vue.js : "$scrollTo" is not defined in inner template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

When I am using another template (Header.vue) inside the main template Index.vue, it throws an error "$scrollTo" is not defined.

Note : $scrollTo is provided by the module "vue2-scrollspy" which I have installed.

***However if I paste the entire code of Header.vue inside Index.vue it works fine.***

**Index.vue**

```
 <template>
      <div class="scroll-div">
        <mainheader></mainheader>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        import mainheader from './Header.vue'
        export default {
            name: 'MyApplication',
            components:{
                mainheader
            }
         }
    </script>
```

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="main-Header">
    <b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" variant="dark" fixed="top">
      <div class="container">
        <b-navbar-brand @click="$scrollTo(0)"></b-navbar-brand>
</div>
    </b-navbar>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name : 'mainheader',
        data () {
          return {
            msg: 'Welcome to SportsBee',
            scrollPos: 0
          }
        }

    }
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
import Scrollspy from 'vue2-scrollspy';

Vue.use(Scrollspy);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router =  new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'index',
        component: index
    }
  ], mode:"history"
})
export default router;
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: It would help if you would clarify in the question that `$scrollTo` is apparently supposed to be provided by `vue2-scrollspy`, a library you are attempting to include.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket `}` in your `Index.vue` code

Comment: Where is your `v-scroll-spy` directive set? I'm guessing it's in the Index.vue. That being the case, $scrollTo, will not be defined in Header.vue, because the directive adds the $scrollTo function to the *current* context, which in that case would be the Index.vue component. https://github.com/ibufu/vue2-scrollspy/blob/e5ff9e2cc4e3f75b37350fb54f45bbfc981343a7/src/index.js#L63

Comment: @Bert , I am new to Vue, can you please tell what all changes should be done to bind the directive in Header.vue

Comment: At this point it would just be me reading the documentation for you. You need to have the `v-scroll-spy` directive and the $scrollTo calls in the *same* component, otherwise I don't expect it to work.